# no such table: current_user (code 1) NO CHANGING DATABASE NAME

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a 1(one) Table at first in my database. Then, I realized that I will add another table in that database.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists profile (" +
            "email text primary key not null, " +
            "username text, " +
            "profilePicture text, " +
            "about text)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    sql = "CREATE TABLE if not exists current_user (" +
            "email text)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    sql = "INSERT INTO current_user(email)" +
            "VALUES ('')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS profile";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS current_user";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    onCreate(db);
}
```

When I want to update the email of my current_user it sends me an exception

```
public void setCurrentEmail(String email){
    ContentValues rsValues = new ContentValues();
    rsValues.put("email", email);

    database.update("current_user", rsValues, null, null);
}

no such table: current_user (code 1):
```

Others say that, you must change the name of the Database for it to work but 
are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you want to preserve data, implement `onUpgrade()`. If you're fine with losing database data, uninstall + reinstall works.

Answer (score 0):

**If you did not uninstall the app** after updating the code of your SQLiteOpenHelper class, then you must.  
The `onCreate()` method is invoked only the 1st time that the db is created. So now there is no table `current_user` in the db.  
Uninstall the app form your device or emulator so the db is deleted and start over.